# BackUp and Restore WebApplication to Newly Created WebApplication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss-3.0

I need to create clone for particular web application on my MOSS server. I have taken full backup for my existing web application from 
**Central Administration > Operations > Perform a Backup**. I just want to know how can I use this backup file and restore it on newly created web application.

Please note that my webapplication has more than 10 different site collections.

Thanks,

Ashish Chotalia

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this is using the Backup/Restore feature in Sharepoint Designer as [described on this site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx).

You can use Backup/Restore to move a site as well.

If you use Infopath forms on your site, carefully check where the forms are stored after moving the site. It can happen that they point to the "old" lists or databases.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue. I had came across this site, but it will allow you to backup/restore single site collection at a time in you webapplication. I have around 30-35 different site collection. Is there any way I can backup and restore all at once?